# PHP_EOL not working in NOWDOC

Tags: html, newline

This question is just to learn about `PHP_EOL;` and `HEREDOC`/`NOWDOC`.

I run this code but the output is badly formatted (all content in a single line). What i expect is a well formatted output with break lines.

**Like this**

[image]

What is the problem?

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'Título 1' => array(
            'description' => 'A.',
            'year' => 2010
        ),
        'Título 2' => array(
            'description' => 'B.',
            'year' => 2008
        ),
        'Título 3' => array(
            'description' => 'C.',
            'year' => 2011
        )
    );

    echo <<<'NOWDOC'
    ---------------------------------------------------
    #List
    ---------------------------------------------------

    NOWDOC;

    echo PHP_EOL;

    foreach($data as $title => $info) {
        echo <<<HEREDOC
        Título: {$title}
        Ano: {$info['year']}
        Descrição: {$info['description']}
    ---------------------------------------------------
    HEREDOC;

        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Comment: The HEREDOC and the PHP_EOL don't really have anything to do with each other here, do they? Can you clarify what goes wrong?

Comment: the content is outputted without break lines.

Comment: Where are you outputting the data, on the console? Where exactly are the breaks missing?

Comment: The break lines of PHP_EOL are available only in the console? I am running this code in browser.

Comment: replace echo PHP_EOL; with echo "<br>";

Comment: @SivagopalManpragada Dude, that is for html format only....

Comment: @anvd put a mime type text/plain in the header and your browser show plain unformatted text instead of HTML.

Comment: HTML doesn't recognize line breaks, you'll need `<br>``

Comment: @Pekka: or surround it with `<pre>` `</pre>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In console, this should work without problems. In a browser add this:

```
header("Content-Type:text/plain");
```

to the top of your script and the browser will render it as plain text.